External DTD not parsing / 'entity not defined error'
I'm not getting the external DTD, a local file in the same folder, to work with a relative or an absolute path. It is not expanding the variable and gives an error in both Firefox and xmlstarlet.
tutorials.xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tutorials SYSTEM "tutorials.dtd">
<tutorials type="web">
  <tutorial>
    <name>XML Tutorial</name>
    <url>https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial</url>
    <author>&writer;</author>
  </tutorial>
  <tutorial>
    <name>HTML Tutorial</name>
    <url>https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial</url>
    <author>&writer;</author>
  </tutorial>
</tutorials>

tutorials.dtd
<!ELEMENT tutorials (tutorial)+>
<!ATTLIST tutorials type CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT tutorial (name,url,author)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY writer "Site by Donald Duck">

Parsing error:
    $ xmlstarlet fo tutorials.xml
    > tutorials.xml:7.21: Entity 'writer' not defined

But valid?
$ xmlstarlet val -d tutorials.dtd tutorials.xml
> tutorials.xml - valid


Firefox I think has an XML parser that doesn't read external DTDs. I don't know about xmlstarlet, perhaps it has a setting/command line option to ensure it resolves external entities like the external DTD.

Updated it, Martin, thanks.

Xmlstarlet offers --dropdtd to remove the declaration when formatting. As a comparison, xmllint offers to load a dtd as it's not loaded by default and entities remain untranslated xmllint --loaddtd --format --noent test.xml. Try with standalone="yes" and also removing that attribute.

You can use a more modern XML parser, like xidel:
To format:
xidel file.xml -e "." --output-format=xml 

yields:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tutorials type="web">
  <tutorial>
    <name>XML Tutorial</name>
    <url>https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial</url>
    <author>&amp;writer;</author>
  </tutorial>
  <tutorial>
    <name>HTML Tutorial</name>
    <url>https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial</url>
    <author>&amp;writer;</author>
  </tutorial>
</tutorials>

It's a more advanced tool compared to xmlstarlet and xmllint. Moreover, it's not stuck with XPath1 like the other tools mentioned.

xidel doesn't understand DTDs (see readme.txt), and corrupts the XML document. With --output-format=xml the text of the author element is changed from &writer; to &amp;writer; (as your reply shows), with --input-format=xml-strict the text is deleted, in both cases with an exit code of zero. (Tested with xidel version 0.9.8 and 0.9.9.)

Of xmlstarlet's commands only canonic (aka c14n), select (sel),
and transform (tr) seem to understand an entity reference like
<doc>&e;</doc>, according to the test shell script below. This
makes pre/post-processing a requirement if using xmlstarlet's other
commands to handle external entities.
To format an XML document, substituting entity values for entity
references (and expanding any CDATA sections), for example:
xmlstarlet select -B -I -t -c / file.xml.
To validate an XML document with a DTD I'd use
xmllint
and stay away from xmlstarlet validate.

#!/bin/sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2064,SC2154

# Test xmlstarlet commands with external general parsed entity.
# - ${xdata} holds data file contents, defaults to a few <e>N</e>
# - ${keepf} non-empty to keep temporary files in $TMPDIR
# - ${dryrun} non-empty to print but not execute commands
# - ${doecho} non-empty to also print commands before executing

skelf=$(mktemp -t "xsskel-$$-XXXXXXXXXX.xml")
dataf=$(mktemp -t "xsdata-$$-XXXXXXXXXX.xml")
idxff=$(mktemp -t "xsidxf-$$-XXXXXXXXXX.xsl")
test "${keepf}" ||
    trap "rm '${skelf}' '${dataf}' '${idxff}'" INT EXIT

printf '%s\n' \
  '<!DOCTYPE skel [<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "'"${dataf}"'">]><doc>&e;</doc>' \
> "${skelf}"
printf '%s' \
  "${xdata:-<e>1</e><e>2</e><e>3</e><e>4</e>}" \
> "${dataf}"
printf '<v/>' | xmlstarlet select -t \
 -e xsl:transform -a version -o 1.0 -b \
 -e xsl:template -a match -o '@*|node()' -b \
   -e xsl:copy -e xsl:apply-templates -a select -o '@*|node()' \
> "${idxff}"    ## identity transform

for cmd  in  c14n ed el fo pyx sel tr val
do
  case ${cmd} in
    (c14n|el|fo|pyx|val)
            set -- ;;
    (ed)    set -- -d '*/*[3]' ;;
    (sel)   set -- -T -t -c / -n ;;
    (tr)    set -- "${idxff}" ;;
    (*)     break ;;
  esac
  set -- xmlstarlet "${cmd}" "$@" "${skelf}"
  if test "${dryrun}${doecho}"; then
    printf '\n\n# command:'; printf " '%s'" "$@"; printf '\n'
  fi
  if ! test "${dryrun}"; then
    "$@"; printf '\n## %s returned %d\n\n' "${cmd}" "$?"
  fi
done

Given a data file containing <e>1</e><e>2</e><e>3</e><e>4</e>
(making it well-formed XML) pyx returns 4 (outputs the doctype but
says Entity 'e' not defined)
while c14n, ed, el, fo, sel, tr, and val all return zero.
But ed, el, and fo (plus val, presumably) fail to expand
the entity reference.
Given a data file containing <a>B</c> (clearly making it non-XML)
the ed, el, and val commands all return zero -- and val even
pronouncing «datafile» - valid -- while c14n, fo, pyx, sel,
and tr return 3, 2, 4, 3, and 6, respectively.

Thank you.
xmlstarlet select -B -I -t -c / file.xml does exactly as needed.
